# CakePHP acl lists

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I've got a small problem, I've denied access to my page but user is still able to access it.

```
    $this->Acl->allow('contributors','Users');
    $this->Acl->deny('contributors','Users/add');
    $this->Acl->deny('contributors','Users/edit');
    $this->Acl->deny('contributors','Users/delete');
```

This is my code for this. I'm allowing Users controllers explicitly, and then deny access to it's actions. but I'm still able to access them. when I deny Users explicitly access is restricted. Am I doing something wrong???

I've checked permissions using 
`$this->Acl->deny('contributors','Users/add');`
and it returns  false, Thus it's denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shota Bakuradze,

if you are working on a system that uses only the AUTH component, you have to use AUTH methods and attributes only.

In case you have set up a system with ACL, then you normally define it the other way around, as it is more secure. E.g.: Denying every action on controller level, than allowing some actions.

The benefit of this procedure is that, in case you forget to allow an action, less (no) harm is done and you will notice it.

**Edit1:**
In addition, what you call *contributors* has to be an ARO, see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1245/Defining-Permissions-Cake-s-Database-ACL).

Comment: what do you exactly mean under reverting Auth methods and attributes?

Comment: do you use ACL as a component at all? if no, check out the AUTH componenents methods/attributes and remove all $this->Acl. If you actually want to use ACL then make sure the call is right, as I suggested under Edit1. Yours

Comment: i exchanged the word that caused trouble.

Comment: I'm using both the ACL and Auth compontents, Everything seems to work fine just cant deny specific actions on controller. when I deny a controller explicitely it works

Comment: have you tried to deny the controller and to allow the actions? Effectively this is the same as denying certain actions.

Comment: what is the name of your root aco?

Comment: root aco is 'controllers' and the 'contributor' is an alias of my aro, I've allowed 'controllers' explicitely, now I need to deny 'Users'

Comment: deny 'controllers', deny 'Users', allow some of the actions. tell me if that solved your issue.

Comment: Geeez, I forgot about my admin routing prefix and was allowing only public actions... Sorry for taking your time, And Thanks... I'm so stupid...

Comment: Happens Ü, glad you fixed it.